# Get a line from a file and append it to another file

Tags: linux, bash

I need to extract a certain line number from a file and then append it another file. New with bash,Please help!

Answer (score 2):

```
head -n<SkipLines> <filename> | tail -n<TakeLines>
```

so if you want to take 2 lines from the 10th of a file **pippo.txt**:

```
head -n10 pippo.txt | tail -n2
```

EDIT:

To append it to another file just do:

```
head -n<SkipLines> <filename> | tail -n<TakeLines> >> <OtherFile>

head -n10 pippo.txt | tail -n2 >> pippo2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Bash≥4.

To extract line 42 from file `inputfile` and append it to file `outputfile` is as simple as:

```
# data

input=inputfile
output=outputfile
linenb=42

# get line number
mapfile -t -s $((linenb-1)) -n 1 line < "$input" || exit 1

# check that we got a line
if ((${#line[@]}==0)); then
    printf >&2 'Line %d not found in file %s\n' "$linenb" "$input"
    exit 1
fi

# append it to output file
printf '%s\n' "$line" >> "$output"
```

Pure Bash!

Comment: Sounds like a little bit of an overhead loading the whole file into an array in memory just to use N lines from that file.

Comment: @andlrc: it doesn't load the whole file at all: it _skips_ the first lines (that's what the `-s` option does) and _stops after reading one line_ (that's what the `-n 1` option does). It's very efficient!

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying :-) I'm gonna read up on `mapfile`